# angular js post data

Tags: javascript, php

Error

> angular.js:14362 TypeError: $http.post(...).success is not a function
>       at ChildScope.$scope.insertData (myjs.js:6)
>       at fn (eval at compile (angular.js:15197), :4:150)
>       at callback (angular.js:26808)
>       at ChildScope.$eval (angular.js:18017)
>       at ChildScope.$apply (angular.js:18117)
>       at HTMLButtonElement. (angular.js:26813)
>       at defaultHandlerWrapper (angular.js:3617)
>       at HTMLButtonElement.eventHandler (angular.js:3605)

​html page:

```
    <body ng-app="mymod">      
       <div class="container" ng-controller="mycontroller">
       <div class="main-head">
       <img src="img/main.jpg" class="img img-thumbnail" alt="main image">

           </div>
       <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-5">

        <form>



  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="firstname">First name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname"  ng-model="firstname" name="firstname">
   </div>


  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname" ng-model="lastname" name="lastname">
  </div>



    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="district">District</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="district" ng-model="district" name="district">
  </div>


  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="dateofborth">Date Of Birth</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker"  ng-model="dob" name="dob">
  </div> 


        <button type="submit"   ng-click="insertData()" class="btn btn-info btn-sm"> Submit</button>     

        </form>                                   

           </div>


                <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-1 right">                                          <table class="table table-condensed">

                    <thead>
                       <tr>
                        <th> First Name</th>
                        <th> Last Name</th>
                        <th> District</th>
                        <th> Date Of Birth</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="student in data">
                        <td>{{ student.firstname }}</td>
                        <td>{{ student.lastname }}</td>
                        <td>{{ student.district }}</td>
                        <td>{{ student.dob }}</td>

                    </tr>
                    </tbody>


                </table>
```

**Insert.php page**

```
include('connectdb.php');


$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

$firstname = $dbhandle->real_escape_string($data->firstname);
$lastname = $dbhandle->real_escape_string($data->lastname);
$district = $dbhandle->real_escape_string($data->district);
$dob = $dbhandle->real_escape_string($data->dob);



$query  = "INSERT INTO students VALUES($id,'".$firstname."','".$lastname."','".$district."','".$dob."')";


$dbhandle->query($query);
```

**js file**

```
var app = angular.module("mymod",[]);
app.controller("mycontroller",function($scope,$http){

$scope.insertData = function(){
    $http.post("insert.php",{'firstname':$scope.firstname,'lastname':$scope.lastname,'district':$scope.district,'dob':$scope.dob})
    .success(function(){    
        $scope.msg = "Data Submitted";

    })


}   



});
```

Please Help Me i cant find error :(
i want send data my db

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$scope.insertData = function($http){
    $http.post("insert.php",{'firstname':$scope.firstname,'lastname':$scope.lastname,'district':$scope.district,'dob':$scope.dob})
    .success(function(){    
        $scope.msg = "Data Submitted";

    })
}
```

Comment: Not Working  :(TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined
    at ChildScope.$scope.insertData (myjs.js:5)
    at fn (eval at compile (angular.js:15197), <anonymous>:4:150)
    at callback (angular.js:26808)
    at ChildScope.$eval (angular.js:18017)
    at ChildScope.$apply (angular.js:18117)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:26813)
    at defaultHandlerWrapper (angular.js:3617)
    at HTMLButtonElement.eventHandler (angular.js:3605)

Comment: Well, it seems your $http is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this $http handler -

```
$http.post('/someUrl', data, config).then(function(res){
     // The Code Here which runs on success callback
  }, function(err){
      // The Code Here which runs on Error callback
 });
```

It returns HttpPromise.